# Data range with BETWEEN in WHERE clause with CONVERT is not filtering correclty

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using below SQL request to get information between 2 dates.

However result containing record out of the range I specified.

**Query**:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, R.RN_EXECUTION_DATE, 103) AS 'Execution Date', 
    R.RN_TESTCYCL_ID, 
    R.RN_STATUS, 
    R.RN_RUN_NAME, 
    T.TS_USER_TEMPLATE_05, 
    RC.RCYC_NAME
FROM R 
    INNER JOIN TC 
        ON R.RN_TESTCYCL_ID = TC.TC_TESTCYCL_ID 
    INNER JOIN RC 
        ON RC.RCYC_ID = TC.TC_ASSIGN_RCYC 
    INNER JOIN T 
        ON R.RN_TEST_ID = T.TS_TEST_ID
WHERE R.RN_STATUS IN ('Passed', 'Failed')
    AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, R.RN_EXECUTION_DATE, 103) BETWEEN '16/11/2020' AND '28/02/2021'
    AND TC.CUSTOM_08 = 'IT5'
    AND (RC.RCYC_NAME LIKE '03_%TI-%' OR RC.RCYC_NAME LIKE 'SIT%')
```

**Result**:

```
Execution Date | ... | ... |
22/12/2020     | ... | ... |
22/01/2021     | ... | ... |
19/06/2020     | ... | ... |
22/07/2020     | ... | ... |
...            | ... | ... |
```

**Data type**

Data type of `RN_EXECUTION_TIME` is `varchar`

```
2018-04-04 00:00:00
2010-01-04 00:00:00
2020-12-10 00:00:00
```

Any error in my query?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: You are doing string comparisons rather than date. And ruining any indexes which might have been helpful for dates otherwise.

Comment: Determine if your date strings are all valid. Run the query `select * from R where try_convert(date, RN_EXECUTION_DATE, 103) is null order by RN_EXECUTION_DATE;`. If that returns rows, you have invalidate dates (or dates of a different format from the 103 style). If so, much pain is in your future.

Comment: @SMor Thank you for your comment. This request is returning 0 rows. Based on your comment it is a good news I guess. Do you have any idea why I'm not able to get correct results please?

Comment: If what you say is correct, then the second statement Gordon gave you should work as long as you use the correct style with the convert function. E.g., `CONVERT(DATE, R.RN_EXECUTION_DATE, 103) BETWEEN '2020-11-16' ...`.

Comment: I agree with you however I'm facing `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string` and I don't understand why ...

Comment: Time to do your analysis of the values you have. Something is invalid according to the style you use for conversion. I overlooked the time portion but invalid times will also cause the conversion to fail. Start running queries to determine if they have a consistent format using a consistent separator, etc. First character must be 0 or 1, there must be no characters outside of [0-9], /, and :, etc. This is all basic debugging - no easy way around it.

Comment: I'll point out that using convert with a varchar expression and style does nothing. The style only applies to expressions of specific datatypes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AND CONVERT(VARCHAR, R.RN_EXECUTION_DATE, 103) BETWEEN '16/11/2020' AND '28/02/2021'
```

Huh?  Why are converting a date to a string for date comparisons?  Just use date comparisons.  You can do:

```
CONVERT(DATE, R.RN_EXECUTION_DATE) BETWEEN '2020-11-16' AND '2021-02-28'
```

However, I prefer no conversions at all:

```
R.RN_EXECUTION_DATE >= '2020-11-16' AND
R.RN_EXECUTION_DATE < '2021-03-01'
```

Note that by getting rid of `BETWEEN`, this works regardless of whether the column has a time component.

EDIT:

Based on the examples of execution date in the question, you can use:

```
TRY_CONVERT(DATE, R.RN_EXECUTION_DATE) >= '2020-11-16' AND
TRY_CONVERT(DATE, R.RN_EXECUTION_DATE) < '2021-03-01'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Because `RN_EXECUTION_DATE` type is varchar. Else I'm facing `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string` or `The conversion of a varchar type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value`. Using `CONVERT(varchar...)` is not the correct way to do?

Comment: @Royce . . . In that case, you should really fix the data model, so it is stored correctly.  In the meantime, you can convert to a *date*, not to a `varchar`.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the data model. So I should use `CONVERT(DATE, R.RN_EXECUTION_DATE)`? When I use this I'm facing following error : `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string`. I don't understand what is wrong here ...

Comment: @Royce . . . Given the sample data in your question, you can use `convert(date, r.rn_execution_date)`.  However, you might want `try_convert_date, r.rn_execution_date)`.

Comment: Thank you it seems to be ok ... So it was the format of the date ...

Answer (score 1):

`CONVERT(VARCHAR, R.RN_EXECUTION_DATE, 103)` will return `varchar` value which you are trying to compare with date field.

Please try this:

```
SELECT 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, R.RN_EXECUTION_DATE, 103) AS 'Execution Date', 
    R.RN_TESTCYCL_ID, 
    R.RN_STATUS, 
    R.RN_RUN_NAME, 
    T.TS_USER_TEMPLATE_05, 
    RC.RCYC_NAME
FROM R 
    INNER JOIN TC 
        ON R.RN_TESTCYCL_ID = TC.TC_TESTCYCL_ID 
    INNER JOIN RC 
        ON RC.RCYC_ID = TC.TC_ASSIGN_RCYC 
    INNER JOIN T 
        ON R.RN_TEST_ID = T.TS_TEST_ID
WHERE R.RN_STATUS IN ('Passed', 'Failed')
    AND R.RN_EXECUTION_DATE BETWEEN '16/11/2020' AND '28/02/2021'
    AND TC.CUSTOM_08 = 'IT5'
    AND (RC.RCYC_NAME LIKE '03_%TI-%' OR RC.RCYC_NAME LIKE 'SIT%')
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. However I'm facing this error : `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string`

Comment: What is the data type of R.RN_EXECUTION_DATE? And please share three sample value from this field.

Comment: First please try without conversion.

Comment: I'm still facing an issue : `The conversion of a varchar type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value`